# Android traceview alternative

Tags: android, trace

Are there some alternative tracing tools which works on android? If there aren't, are there some good alternatives for measuring bottlenecks? (I ask because i have many problems with traceview)

Answer (score 0):

I posted yesterday a similar question [Profiling Android apps with Eclipse plugin TPTP instead of traceview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507816/profiling-android-apps-with-eclipse-plugin-tptp-instead-of-traceview). I found someone who was able to view Android trace file with the Eclipse Test and Performance Tools Platform (TPTP), the standard tool for profiling an application in Eclipse. Unfortunately I didn't manage to convert .trace file into .trcxml file (that is the format used by TPTP). I'll let you know if I discover something usefull.

---

**Edit 1**

I found some interesting tool you can use to analyze Android apps memory usage. In order to get memory usage from Eclipse you have to "Dump HPROF file" from the DDMS prospective. Before doing that you have to choose in the DDMS preference panel, when it says "HPROF Action", the "Save to disk" action. So from now on when you dump HPROF file you'll be asked where you want to save your .hprof file. You have to convert this file with the Android tool "hprof-conv" you can find in your Android SDK installation under the directory "./tools". Finally now you can use the [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) plugin to view the memory usage stats. I hope it will help someone else. If anyone knows something else about profiling Android apps it will appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I finished my Android application and I moved to something else.